# Between operator for date comparison not working properly in MS Access DB query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have simple query as

```
Select *
from myTable tran

Where  tran.Party = 13  
AND  
Format(TransactionDate,'dd-mmm-yyyy') BETWEEN #07-Jan-2020# AND #11-Feb-2020#
```

Which returns just one record where transaction date is "07-Jan-2020" and not other records which are falling between these dates.

**Update**

[image]

**Update 2:**

Instead of between operator if I use 'Greater Than' && 'Less Than' operator:

```
Select * from CylinderTransactions tran

Where  tran.Party = 13  AND
Format(TransactionDate,'dd-mm-yyyy') >= #07-Jan-2020# 
AND Format(TransactionDate,'dd-mm-yyyy') <= #11-Feb-2020#
```

Than it gets 3 records one from 7th Jan and 2 from 11th Feb, but still one record of 15th Jan (Please refer previous snapshot of actual data.

Comment: What does the original data look like?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Updated my question with Actual Data

Comment: @RobertHarvey Any clue ?

Comment: If TransactionDate's data type is Date/Time remove the function Format and compare TransactionDate.

Comment: @forpas Seems something was messed up with this Format function, after removing that format, its working fine.

Comment: Format a date, and it's no longer a date, it is a string. BETWEEN AND expects dates.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Understood, thanks for the information. I appreciate it :).

Comment: Do note that if TransactionDate contains a time part, then `#11-Feb-2020#` will be interpreted as midnight so it will ignore the rest of the day (solution: use `< #12-Feb-2020#` or rather `< #2020-02-12#`)

Answer (score 1):

Filter on the date value itself and never use literal months:

```
Where  
    tran.Party = 13  
    AND
    TransactionDate BETWEEN #2020/01/07# AND #2020/02/11#
```